# How do I add (push) items to an array one at a time (looping through array)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, push

I can't figure this weird problem out. [Link to Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/posedu/edit?html,js,console,output)

I'm trying to add values to an array (`prices`), using a click function. When the user clicks a button, it adds pricing data to a Javscript array `prices`.

I need to add multiple data entries at once, that contain the price but different `day`.

This is my click function for #add_pricing.

```
$("#add_pricing").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    data = {
        "price": "1200",
        "days": ["1","3","4"]
    }
    addData(data);
    console.log(prices)
});
```

So when the user clicks that, as you can see it sends the `data` variable to addData, which is:

```
function addData(data)
{
    for (i = 0; i < data.days.length; i++){
        data.day = data.days[i]; //eg. data.day = "1"
        prices.push(data);

    }
}
```

So the `addData()` function loops through data.days and I want it to push an entry to the `prices` array, but one at a time.

But instead it seems to push all 4 items at a time for every itteration (you can see if you log the output)

[image]

AND it doesn't set my day variable properly, day is ALWAYS set to 4, even though if I log the output, it seems to be displaying the correct one.

[image]

Expected output:

```
[1] => {day: 1, price: 1200}
[2] => {day: 3, price: 1200}
[3] => {day: 3, price: 1200}
```

Actual output

```
[1] => {day: 4, price: 1200}
[2] => {day: 4, price: 1200}
[3] => {day: 4, price: 1200}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just modifying the `day` property of `data` over and over again. The `data` object is never recreated.

Did you mean to do this?

```
function addData(data)
{
    for (i = 0; i < data.days.length; i++){
        data.day = data.days[i]; //eg. data.day = "1"
        prices.push(data.day); // push data.day?

    }
}
```

If you actually want to clone the object, you can use [JQuery's extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) to do so. Or if you're in node, the [extend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extend) module does the same thing.

```
function addData(data)
{
    for (i = 0; i < data.days.length; i++){
        var newData = $.extend({}, data);
        newData.day = data.days[i]; //eg. data.day = "1"
        prices.push(newData);

    }
}
```

If the object in your real code is as simple as the one you've used in your question, then it may be easier to just create a new object:

```
function addData(data)
{
    for (i = 0; i < data.days.length; i++){
        prices.push({
          price: data.price,
          day: data.days[i]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No I want to push data multiple times to the array, but each time with a modified day value.

Comment: In the end having an array that's three items long, each item has a price and a day value (like 1 or 3)

Comment: Thanks, both those things are useful to know

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work

```
function addData(data)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < data.days.length; i++){
                prices.push({ day: data.days[i], price: data.price  });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks that does pretty much what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
prices.push(data);
```

To:

```
prices.push({ day: data.days[i], price: data.price  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
function addData(data)
{
    for (i = 0; i < data.days.length; i++){
        data.day = data.days[i]; //eg. data.day = "1"
        prices.push(data[i]); //this needs to only add the current object not the entire array of objects

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing multiple references to the same object. On each iteration of the loop you modify the `.day` property of *the same object*.

You need to create a *new* object *within the loop* and push that:

```
function addData(data)
{
    for (i = 0; i < data.days.length; i++){
        prices.push({
          day : data.days[i],
          price : data.price
        });    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 function addData(data)
 {
    for (i = 0; i < data.days.length; i++){
       data.day = data.days[i]; //eg. data.day = "1"
       if(prices.length > 0)
          prices[prices.length] = data;
       else 
          prices[0] = data;
    }
}
```